# Wordpress theme entypo css character/icon?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I am trying to add entypo icon on image hover in wordpress theme, but it is showing as letter or character, in case I will use one code example, and in this code on hover entypo is showing ", **Quotation Marks**.

```
<div class="large-thumbnail">
<a href="url" title=""> 
<img width="400" height="220" src="image.jpg" class="image" alt="image"></a>
</div>

.large-thumbnail:hover a:after {
content: "\0022";
font: 48px/.75 'EntypoRegular';
height: 36px;
width: 32px;
margin-right: 5px;
vertical-align: -2px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
_height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the font?

Comment: @Paulie_D, I don't know what you mean. This is first time I am trying to use entypo characters, this code up is everything I have. I used this source: http://jsfiddle.net/jozecuervo/8TWuL/

Comment: If you don't load the font (probably using `@font-face`) first your browser will not recognise the font when you reference it in your CSS. Try examining the jsfiddle you linked more closely.